# Calling SQL Procedure inside another python Procedure in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to call SQL Procedure inside another Stored Python procedure. How to do it ?
I'm working on project that needs to execute SQL transformations before doing modelling, Initially i had done transformations using python, but now i need to convert it to SQL.

for example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE output_message(message VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR NOT NULL
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN message;
END;
$$
;


CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SECOND_PROC()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
HANDLER = 'main'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
def main(session):
    query = "CALL output_message('hello there')";
    snowflake.execute( {sqlText:query} );
$$;

CALL SECOND_PROC();



this is returning "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake' in function SECOND_PROC with handler main"
```

Comment: Haven’t you missed the PACKAGES line from the Python SP definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @NickW said in a comment, the solution is to add packages to the Python stored procedure definition.

You also need to call `session.sql()` instead of `snowflake.execute()`:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SECOND_PROC()
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE PYTHON
RUNTIME_VERSION = '3.8'
PACKAGES = ('snowflake-snowpark-python')
HANDLER = 'main'
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$

def main(session):
    query = "CALL output_message('hello there')";
    return session.sql(query).collect();   
$$;
```